# Для чего в этом интерфейсе объявлена константа ZERO?

Tags: java

```
public interface Money {
    Money ZERO = new ZeroMoneyImpl();

    Money add(Money other);

    Money multiply(BigDecimal multiplier);
}
```

Comment: а почему бы и нет?

Comment: Это скорее всего использование паттерна [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Остается только гадать, т.к. мы ничего не знаем о реализации ZeroMoneyImpl и сути самой программы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно смотреть основную программу, чтобы понять. А причин для этого может быть много:

1. Оптимизация а) - если у нас много где создается класс ZeroMoneyImpl то имеет смысл закешировать его, тогда не нужно будет создавать одинаковые объекты через new.
2. Оптимизация б) - если нужно фильтровать классы, как то в духе if (notZero), то вместо equals можно вызывать ==.
3. Для удобства и краткости, возможно понятности. Например `balance = Zero`.

... и многое другое. Но мне лично кажется, конкретно в этом случае объявление константы в этом интефейсе выглядит странным.

По крайней мере в джаве распростаннен подход, когда создается отдельный интефейс для реализаций, по умолчанию. Например интерфейс Collector и реализации по умолчанию доступны через интерфейс Collectors. А так как Money вряд ли будут создаваться анонимно и скорее всего будут доступны через реализацию в духе MoneyImpl, то и ZERO лучше разместить где нибудь в Moneys.